# ¿Como manipular los indices del metodo random? java

Tags: java

Quiero generar numeros aleatorios con random.

```
int num = (int)(Math.random()*8);
```

pero poder manipular los indices, ya que el genera los numeros desde cero por defecto pero yo quiero
que la aleaccion sea de 1 a 8 o de 2 a 4, etc
no se cual seria su sintaxis.

Comment: porque la primer respuesta fue eliminada?

Comment: Me di cuenta de que no era del todo correcta

Answer (score 1):

También tienes una posibilidad de poder declarar el número menor y el mayor para que el `random` este entre esos dos números.

```
  Random r = new Random();
    int menor = 1;
    int mayor = 8;
    int resultado = r.nextInt(mayor-menor) + menor;
    System.out.println(resultado);
```

Comment: Creo que deberías de leer la documentación de esa clase.... no tiene caso que uses una clase random cuando podrías llamar al método estático.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres números aleatorios entre un rango incluidos los límites (números del 1 al 8 incluidos el 1 y el 8) debes usar la siguiente formula.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(mayor-menor+1)+menor);
```

En este ejemplo donde se generan números aleatorios te darás cuenta que números imprime.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int menor = 1;
    int mayor = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      int numero = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(mayor-menor+1)+menor);
      System.out.println(numero);
    }
  }
}
```

En mi caso imprimó `6,8,4,2,5,6,1,2,1,6` y cómo puedes ver está incluido el 1 y el 8.

Si quieres un método que genere números aleatorios enteros puedes usar esto:

```
int numeroAleatorio(int menor, int mayor) {
  return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (mayor - menor + 1) + menor);
}
```